# Persists Java object in postgresql in a range type

Tags: java, postgresql, range

I have a Postgres table with several columns of type `numrange` and `int4range`.

I want to persist data in it from Java. Currently I have this data in a Java class like this:

```java
class Range<T> {
    private Integer minimum;
    private Integer maximum;
    // more code...
}
```

I'm using the JDBC Driver and the `java.sql.*`and I've tried several things, without success:

```java
pstmt.setObject(7, myObject.price()); // price() returns a Range object
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of com.scmspain.admatching.domain.Range. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

I cannot specify the type, since it does not exist in the `java.sql.Types` class.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by using the `Types.OTHER`.

```java
pstmt.setObject(7, myObject.price(), Types.OTHER);
```

It was also required to include a `toString()` method in my `Range` class:

```
class Range<T> {
    // more code...

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%d, %d]", minimum, maximum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another possible approach is to write a class that extends [`PGobject`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/PGobject.html) to provide an implementation of the range type, and a method that takes a `Range<T>` as a ctor argument. This would be cleaner, strictly, than baking details of PostgreSQL's range type representation into the `Range<T>` class.

Comment: @CraigRinger I agree with you. I didn't know about the `PGobject`. Thanks for your opinion.